# IR sensor not showing result on serial monitor

Tags: arduino, infrared

I am trying to display the value received by an IR sensor on the serial monitor.
The sensor blinks the led when I press a button but does not show anything on the serial monitor. I am using my own made AVR test bed based on the Arduino Uno

Sorry for the bad picture quality.

[image: Breadboard circuit]

I am pressing the power button of my Sony rm-gd023 remote and the led blinks but nothing on the serial monitor. I have included the source code below.

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

You should download the IR sensor library: 
https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B1Hqp8fKfwy4MTlNZzFJdzdoTTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It might be better to draw a circuit diagram, it's hard to make out much from the photo. Also have you checked the serial generally works, say by printing "Hello" after `Serial.begin`?

Comment: Have you ascertained that the serial communications are working at all? In code like this it's always good to have it print some welcome message, or even a periodic "still alive" message to serial.

Comment: Testing the serial lines is useful and should definitely be done, but I'll bet that the call `irrecv.decode(&results))` is returning `false`, that's why you don't see anything on the serial monitor. The question now is **why?**

Comment: I'm working on an IR remote control as well, so I'll set up the circuit myself tonight and will give it a try. I'll report back here if I find anything else.

Comment: Add a call to `irrecv.blink13(true)` in the setup and attach an LED and a limiting resistor in series to pin 13 to see if it blinks when the lib is receiving the signal.

Comment: I got this suggestion from [this site](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_IRremote.html), but they seem to have modified the lib for their product, so the blink call may not work directly in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my answer.

The Max232 ic should be used or a TTL level USB dongle can be used for the serail.print command or other serial commands to work on my own made board because because my programmer does not give me the RX and the TX lines for the TTL level commnunication.